# My mac book won't run tor after being moved to applications

Tags: mac, tor-install

After downloading Version 5.5.5 - OS X (10.6+) and moving it to applications on my mac book (TorBrowser-5.5.5-osx64en-US.dmg) and verifying I want to open it, my computer prompts "Tor Browser Profile Problem" stating "You cannot run Tor Browser from a read-only file system.  Please copy Tor Browser to your Desktop or Applications folder before trying to use it.". I have tried moving to desk top and applications but to no avail. My security settings are allowing apps to be downloaded from anywhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: Extract the application from the .dmg file first.